# MERGING 3 TABLES INTO ONE AND INSERTING INTO DATABASE

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I am trying to combine 3 tables into 1 in my database. 
My table names = table1, table2, table3
I'm inserting the data into table4 
Each table has columns of code, team, p1, p2, p3

IT IS NOT GOING INTO THE DATABASE.

I want the merged insert in the database to look like the following:

code, team,  name 1,  name 2,  name 3, name 4, name 5, name 6, name 7, name 8, name 9

HERE ARE MY TABLES with COLUMNS
table 1: name 1, name 2, name 3
table 2: name 4, name 5, name 6
table 3: name 7, name 8, name 9

This is what I have so far but it is not working. Any help?

```
INSERT INTO table4
VALUES (code,team,name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6,name7,name8,name9)
SELECT table1.code1, 
       table1.team1, 
       table1.name1, 
       table1.name2, 
       table1.name3, 
       table2.name4, 
       table2.name5, 
       table2.name6, 
       talbe3.name7, 
       table3.name8, 
       table3.name9 
FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.team = table2.team  
AND table3.team = table1.team
AND table3.team = table2.team
INSERT INTO table4 VALUES ($code, $team, $name1, $name2, $name3, $name4, $name5, $name6,     
$name7, $name8, $name9);
```

Comment: `'name 1'` does not sound like a valid column name, what type of db are you using?

Comment: how is it not working? what error is thrown?

Comment: you have used `SELECT` code for inserting data?

Comment: if your column names are actually `name 1`, `name 2`, etc. you need to add backticks around them `\`name 1\``, `\`name 2\``, etc. Although spaces in column names is never a good idea. Also, where is your `INSERT INTO ...` as this only shows a `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were getting errors because you had a trailing comma after `name 9`, and you also shouldn't have spaces in the names. Assuming you didnt actually want spaces, we can also optimize your query into proper ANSI syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table4 (code,team,name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6,name7,name8,name9)
SELECT TableOne.code
    ,TableOne.team
    ,TableOne.name1
    ,TableOne.name2
    ,TableOne.name3
    ,TableTwo.name4
    ,TableTwo.name5
    ,TableTwo.name6
    ,TableThree.name7
    ,TableThree.name8
    ,TableThree.name9 
FROM table1 AS TableOne
INNER JOIN table2 AS TableTwo ON TableTwo.team = TableOne.team
INNER JOIN table3 AS TableThree ON TableThree.team = TableTwo.team
```

The aliases assume `code` comes from `table1`. I assume you were getting an ambiguous error for your `SELECT` of `team`, on top of the trailing comma after `name9`.

Comment: Made your corrections and still not going into database.

Comment: modified to include the `INSERT INTO` that is necessary to put into a database. unless your columns have the `$` in the name, you shouldn't include them, and the `INSERT INTO` statement precedes the `SELECT`. if you still do not get any values, run the `SELECT` statement alone to ensure you are actually returning values.

Comment: MY ERROR---- #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT table1.code ,table1.team ,table1.name1 ,table1.name3' at line 4

Comment: BY THE WAY----Im putting this code directly in phpmyadmin sql

Comment: that was my bad for copy and paste, you don't include `VALUES` when using that `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

Comment: NEW ERROR ---- #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'TABLE2'

Comment: *sigh* updated my aliases to no longer match the table names.

Comment: haha glad to hear it. since its working, mind providing the checkmark? :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so dude ... as i understood your question, you are going to merging table or something similar. 
Now in you query you are just selecting the data from three table, but nit inserting it into the 4 table. 
for that you have to store SELECTED result into variable or array and later on insert it into the 4 table one by one .. 
Take a reference of Google; if you stacked some where ...

All the best (Y)